# Magento 2 How to duplicate the category with same structure?

Tags: magento2, admin, category, category-products, category-tree

I want to **duplicate the category** with the same structure and data.

**How to duplicate child categories here? It is working correctly for a single category.**

In my controller file, I have the **parent category id** and **category id** which needs to duplicate. **Now how can I create duplication of a category**?

Please check my code is as below:

```
class DuplicateCategory extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action {
protected $_categoryFactory;
public function __construct(
\Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
) {
parent::__construct($context);
$this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
}

$parentCategoryObj = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load(2);
$duplicateCategoryObj = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load(8);
$catagoryObject = $this->_categoryFactory->create();

$categoryName = $duplicateCategoryObj->getName();
$categoryUrlKey = strtolower($this->getCategoryUrlKey($categoryName));

$catagoryObject->setPath($parentCategoryObj->getPath())
->setParentId($parentCategory)
->setName($duplicateCategoryObj->getName())
->setUrlKey($categoryUrlKey)
->setStoreId($storeId)
->setIsActive(true);
$catagoryObject->save();
}
```